# How to add a confirmation to powershell script?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have a script to undeploy my solution and I want to simply add a confirmation message. I found hundrets of blog entries, how to remove a confirmation via `-confirm:$false` parameter, but I find the opposite.

Something like this:

```
Write-Host "Are you shure that you want to remove the given solution (this can't be undone)?"

if (confirm() ) {
    Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity $wspIdentitySTR -confirm:$false
    .
    .
    .   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pulled from some really old PS1 code*

Doesn't this work anymore?

```
$ServerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the server name?'
```